# Navigation Drawer icons not showing

Tags: android, menuitem, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I am using Android Studio's Navigation Drawer Template.  I have replaced the icons and text in the navigation drawer menu with my own.  You can see the menu items' text just fine, but both icons are missing.  I am, temporarily, using the same icon for both.  The icon is a .png in my drawable folder, heart_full.  (It is the same heart icon that you can see along the right side of the MainActivity behind the navigation drawer.)

[image: Missing navigation drawer icons]

Here is my navigation drawer menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_routes"
        android:icon="@drawable/heart_full"
        android:title="Routes"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_favorites"
        android:icon="@drawable/heart_full"
        android:title="Favorites"/>
</group>
```

I setup the drawer in onCreate with the following code:

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Does any code look suspect or am I missing something altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I had the following in my styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Apparently, it is also responsible for the color of navdraw menu icons. White icons on white background are not visible.